# Relate Code-First to Identity ApplicationUser in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I have a Core 2.0 project that has reached the point where I need to start linking users to the data I have. It started as a one user test bed that now requires me to have multiple  per user.

User Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Balance> Balances { get; set; }
}
```

Balance model:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
 ...
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
//Users to balances
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
       .HasMany(b => b.Balances)
       .WithOne(u => u.User);
```

In my code, when creating a new Balance, I cannot figure out how to link my current logged in user:

```
var myNewBalance = new Balance();
myNewBalance.User = User;
                     ^ boom
```

How do I relate Balances to the currently logged in user?

Comment: boom is where it errors... it's a common term used in 101% of the USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_User) property you've highlighted in your question is a `ClaimsPrincipal` that belongs to the `ControllerBase` class. The `User` property on your `Balance` class is an `ApplicationUser`, which is not compatible with `ClaimsPrincipal`. You already know this, but I'm just making it explicit in order to explain what you need to do.

As you are using ASP.NET Core Identity here, you can use the [`UserManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0) class, which is available using dependency injection. `UserManager` contains a function, [`GetUserAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_GetUserAsync_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_), that can convert your `ClaimsPrincipal` into the corresponding `ApplicationUser`.

Here's some code:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public SomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction()
    {
        var myNewBalance = new Balance();
        myNewBalance.User = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        return View(); // etc, etc.
    }
}
```

The key points are the use of the generic `UserManager` that uses `ApplicationUser` and then the invocation of `GetUserAsync` using the `User` (`ClaimsPrincipal`) property.